# Why should a valid diversity measure be independent of the target variable?

Tags: ensemble-learning, diversity

Consider an ensemble of weak learners (i.e. regressors or classifiers) whose predictions are aggregated (e.g. via averaging or majority vote) into an ensemble estimate.

This gives rise to the question when exactly building an ensemble is better than simply using a single member. Quantifying this effect leads to the notion of "diversity" for which several approaches/definitions have been proposed.

Now,

> It is arguable that [such a measure] can only be referred to as "diversity" when the measure is independent of the target variable y. [[source](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/616302/178468)}

**Why is that?** Diversity, as understood e.g. in [1] is a function of member estimates anyways, i.e. dependent on $X$. Where's the harm in a formulation also dependent on $Y$?

---

[1] Wood et al, 2023. "A Unified Theory of Diversity in Ensemble Learning arXiv:2301.03962v1, https://arxiv.org/pdf/2301.03962.pdf

[2] Zhou, Z. H. (2014). Ensemble methods. Combining pattern classifiers. Wiley, Hoboken, 186-229.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "harm" in a formulation of diversity dependent on Y.  It's simply a definition, such that the word `diversity' is used when we measure a property that is solely due to the ensemble outputs, and not a function the true labels.

One could say there are two "types" of diversity, one label-independent, and one dependent.

A reason to prefer the label-independent form is that diversity can be estimated without additional training data labels --- simply query the ensemble for a variety of inputs x, and you can estimate its diversity.  The same applies for `variance' --- you can estimate the variance of any model, without additional training data labels.  The interesting thing about reference [1] is that it shows this label-independent form is not possible for all losses/combiners, but only a subset.

Disclosure: I'm an author of [1].